# asp.net code for retrieving posted data in html

Tags: html, asp.net

I have written html code for posting checkbox value

```
<form action="Default2.aspx" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="attempt" value="101"> I'st attempt<br>
```

2nd attempt

then how should i write the code for accessing this posted value in c#asp ?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    NameValueCollection nvc = context.Request.Form;
  string  userName = nvc["c1"];
 string   passWord = nvc["c2"];
 TextBox1.Text = userName;
 TextBox2.Text = passWord;
}
```

its not working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a runat server control

```
<input type="checkbox" runnat="server" id="c1" name="attempt" value="101">
```

Then you can refer to it directly as c1 in the codebehind